# Delete to the end of a paragaph, including all of the current line

Tags: neovim, cut-copy-paste, cursor-motions

I'd like to redefine the `{` and `}` motions to operate "linewise" when used with the `c` and `d` operators.

To be concrete, given the following:

```
The quick brown
fox j|umps over
the lazy dog
```

If I press `d}`, with the default behaviour, I am left with

```
The quick brown
fox j
```

But I would prefer to be left with

```
The quick brown
```

Similarly, going in the other direction, `d{` currently yields

```
umps over
The lazy dog
```

And I want

```
the lazy dog
```

And of course the equivalent for `c`.

The desired is consistent with with that of other motions which span multiple lines, e.g. `dj`, `dG`, and feels more natural to me.

What is the simplest way of implementing this change?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to redefine the { and } motions to operate "linewise"

Motions are typed in the operator-pending mode. The "linewise" `:h forced-motion` is performed with `:h o_V` So you have to type `dV}`, `cV}` etc.